# Find and return longest sequence of ascending numbers in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of numbers, I am looking for a way to find the longest sequence with removing any outliers. So in other words, it doesn't necessarily have to be a sequence originally, but in the output it should be.
this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence
converted to Javascript would do
for inputs...

```
[0,2,4,12,6] //expected output: [0,2,4,6]  
[1,3,7,5] //expected output: [1,3,5]  
[2,4,6,8] //expected output: [2,4,6,8]  
[6,4,2,5] //expected output: [2,5]  
//I thought maybe something like... but not luck 
const cleanCodes = (codes) => {
    var cleaned = codes.map((code, i) => {
        if(i<codes.length-1){
            if(code[i+1]>code){
                return code;
            }
        }else{
            return code;
        }
    })
    return cleaned;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried coding anything yet? Where are you stuck? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) if you're not sure where to begin.

Comment: @ggorlen what you sent is exactly what I needed. But in javascript haha thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function doSomething(main) {
       
        console.log(main)

        var cop = Object.assign([], main)
        cop.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b })
        let arra = main.slice(main.indexOf(cop[0]))

        //get diff mode
        let diff = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
            diff[i] = arra[i + 1] - arra[i]
        }
        diff.sort();

        let counts = []
        diff.forEach(function (x) { counts[x] = [x, Number(diff[x] || 0) + 1] })

        let reg = counts.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b[1] - a[1]
        })[0][0]


        let result = [arra[0]]
        let temp = Object.assign([], arra);
        for (let i = 1; i < arra.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i - 1] == temp[i] - reg)
                result[i] = temp[i]
            else {
                temp[i] = temp[i - 1]
            }
        }

        console.log(result)
    }


    function test() {
        doSomething([0, 2, 4, 12, 6]);
        doSomething([1, 3, 7, 5]);
        doSomething([2, 4, 6, 8]);
        doSomething([6, 4, 2, 5])
    }

</script>
```